# Adding a Team entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, projects-and-solutions

I have created a record of the entity type "**Team**" which I'm trying to package into a solution that will be imported later in our Test environment.

I can import the "Team" entity, but since it's "**Managed**" (I think) it cannot be edited much.

Is it even possible to include the **Team** I created into my solution ?

Thank you.

Comment: did you create a new team record (standard entity) or did you create a new custom entity with the name Team?

Comment: No, I created a Team record, from the standard entity. Unless I am mistaken, I think this entity is part of the CRM 2011 default solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot include the Team record that you created in your solution. This is true for most CRM entities but when it comes to solution imports we commonly see this issue for users, teams, and queues - all of which may be required by a solution but cannot be included in the solution.

The Team will need to be created in the destination organization before or after importing the solution.

The Microsoft whitepaper [Deploying CRM 2011 from Dev through Test and Production](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27824) goes into significant detail on deploying solutions with these types of dependencies.